# google chart function reading as string

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var arrayAddColumn = ["'string', 'Ano'", "'number', 'Ativo'", "{'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip'}", "'number', 'Extra'", "{'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip'}"];
```

I´m looping the array this way:

```
for(var x=0; x<arrayAddColumn.length;x++){
    dataTable.addColumn(arrayAddColumn[x]);
}
```

The output should be something like this:

```
dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Ano');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Ativo');
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip'});
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Extra');
dataTable.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip'});
```

But the function is reading the position in the array as a string and i need it to be 2 strings separated by a comma.
How can i output something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var arrayAddColumn = [['string', 'Ano'],    
                      ['number', 'Ativo'], 
                      [{'type': 'string'}, {'role': 'tooltip'}]];

for(var x=0; x<arrayAddColumn.length;x++){
     dataTable.addColumn(arrayAddColumn[x][0], arrayAddColumn[x][1]);
}
```